# programmatically set up a @PersistenceContext

Tags: java, jpa, ejb

How can I pro grammatically set up a @PersistenceContext so that I can get the configuration (jDBC Url, Driver Class , etc.) from a simple properties file (so the users can simply modify this file) instead of the bigger and more complex persistence.xml file?

What I have read is that using `Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("bla", properties)` will be completly useless because then `@PersistenceContext(unitName = "bla")` will never work (and it does not work, giving NPEs ...).

I know there are many tutorials but they all use the persistence.xml with an hard coded database type (Oracle, MySQL, ...) and no one explained how I can set up this managed bean programaitcally?

Comment: Who are these users?

Comment: @Steve C me for example

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have provided an `ejb` tag I assume that you're executing in a complete Java EE environment.

Your users should never have to touch the persistence.xml because it would normally be configured with a datasource reference:

```
<persistence-unit name="bla" transaction-type="JTA">
   <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/BlaDS</jta-data-source>
   ...
```

The users then use the tools provided by their Java EE server implementation to create the data source.

Most implementations provide both GUI and CLI tools for performing this task.

For example in WildFly a CLI script might look like:

```
# Execute offline
embed-server --server-config=standalone.xml

deploy postgresql-42.0.0.jre7.jar

# Add the application datasource
data-source add \
    --name=BlaDS \
    --driver-name=postgresql-42.0.0.jre7.jar \
    --connection-url=jdbc:postgresql://bladb-host:5432/bladb \
    --jndi-name=java:jboss/datasources/BlaDS \
    --user-name=bla \
    --password=bla-password \
    --use-ccm=false \
    --min-pool-size=10 \
    --max-pool-size=25 \
    --pool-prefill=true \
    --blocking-timeout-wait-millis=5000 \
    --new-connection-sql="set datestyle = ISO, European;"
```

Normally users would need the ability to control other database connection related attributes like connection pools sizes, etc as shown.